# How to print element inside another element repeatedly in Angular2?

Tags: algorithm, angular

Suppost I have an array of strings:

```
s : Array<string>=['Layer 1','Layer 2','Layer 3','Layer 4','Layer 5'];
```

it is easy to iterate and print them linearly:

```
<div *ngFor="let st of s">{{st}}</div>
```

but what if I want to enclose div into another div like this:

```css
div{
  border-color:black;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:3px;
}
```

```html
<div>Layer 1
  <div>Layer 2
    <div>Layer 3
      <div>Layer 4
        <div>Layer 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is there angular function to print the div in div like this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't do this natively in Angular. The easiest way is to create your own `nested-div` component

**nested-div.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'nested-div',
    templateUrl: './nested-div.component.html',
    styles: [`nested-div { display: block; }`]
})
export class NestedDivComponent {

    @Input() layers: string[];

    constructor() { }

    get hasMoreLayers(): boolean{
        return this.layers.length > 1;
    }
}
```

**nested-div.component.html**

```
{{ layers[0] }}<nested-div *ngIf="hasMoreLayers" [layers]="layers | slice:1"></nested-div>
```

This will generate the nested div structure that you're after

Answer (score 0):

I am able to enclose one div in another div by taking the index of the *ngFor and giving each layer that much amount of `margin-left`. This is what I came up with:

```
<div *ngFor="let st of s;let i = index">
        <span [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': i + 'rem' }">{{st}}</span>
    </div>
```

Here's a plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/JZ6hVM3KVfjbnJe0zGTe?p=preview